If all critical points of $\varphi$ in $\text{spt } \psi$ are non-degenerate, then $\left|\int e^{i\lambda\varphi}\psi\right| \lesssim \lambda^{-n/2}$
This is Theorem $14.5$ in Mattila's Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension. At the beginning of the chapter, the author defines $$I(\lambda) = \int e^{i\lambda\varphi(x)}\psi(x)\, dx,$$
for $\lambda > 0$, and assumes that (i) $\varphi: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ and $\psi: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb C$ are infinitely differentiable, and (ii) $\operatorname{spt}\psi \subset \Bbb R^n$ is compact.

Theorem $14.5$: If all critical points of $\varphi$ in $\text{spt } \psi$ are non-degenerate, then
$$
|I(\lambda)| \leq C(\varphi, \psi) \lambda^{-n/2} \quad \text{for } \lambda > 0.
$$

The proof is inductive, and is done for special quadratic polynomials $\varphi$. I have asked one question at the end.

We may assume that $\text{spt } \psi \subset B(0, 1)$, $\|\psi\|_\infty \leq 1$, $\|\nabla \psi\|_\infty \leq 1$, and $\|H_\varphi\|_\infty \leq 1$. We first consider the case where $\varphi$ is a special quadratic polynomial, $\varphi = Q$:
$$
Q(x) = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_k^2 - x_{k+1}^2 - \cdots - x_n^2
$$
for some $k = 1, \ldots, n$. We use induction on $n$ to prove that for any special quadratic polynomial $Q$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as above and for any smooth $\psi$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\text{spt } \psi \subset B(0, 1)$ and with $\|\partial^\alpha \psi\|_\infty \lesssim_n 1$ for any partial derivative $\partial^\alpha$ of order $|\alpha| \leq n$,
$$
\left| \int e^{i\lambda Q(x)} \psi(x) \, dx \right| \lesssim_n \lambda^{-n/2}.
$$
The case $n = 1$ follows from Corollary $14.3$. Suppose the result holds for $n-1$ and let $\psi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be as above. By Fubini's theorem,
$$
I(\lambda) = \lambda^{-1/2} \int e^{i\lambda(x_2^2 + \cdots + x_k^2 - x_{k+1}^2 - \cdots - x_n^2)} \psi_\lambda(x_2, \ldots, x_n) \, d(x_2, \ldots, x_n),
$$
where
$$
\psi_\lambda(x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \lambda^{1/2} \int e^{i\lambda x_1^2} \psi(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \, dx_1.
$$
Corollary $14.3$ applied to $\psi$ and its partial derivatives tells us that $\|\partial^\alpha \psi_\lambda\|_\infty \lesssim_n 1$ for $|\alpha| \leq n-1$. The induction hypothesis gives that
$$
\left| \int e^{i\lambda(x_2^2 + \cdots + x_k^2 - x_{k+1}^2 - \cdots - x_n^2)} \psi_\lambda(x_2, \ldots, x_n) \, d(x_2, \ldots, x_n) \right| \lesssim \lambda^{(1-n)/2}.
\tag{7}$$
The theorem follows from these for such quadratic polynomials. The general case is a consequence of Morse's lemma.

Question: I'd like to understand the use of Corollary $14.3$ in the final step, where the conclusion is $\|\partial^\alpha \psi_\lambda\|_\infty \lesssim_n 1$ for $|\alpha| \leq n-1$. How do they get this for $|\alpha| \ne 0$? It's a direct application of Corollary $14.3$ to get $\|\psi_\lambda\|_\infty \lesssim_n 1$ through $|\int e^{i\lambda x_1^2} \psi(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \, dx_1| \lesssim \lambda^{-1/2}$.
For reference, this is Corollary $14.3$:

Corollary $14.3$: Suppose $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots \}$ is such that $|\varphi^{(k)}(x)| \geq 1$ for $x \in [a, b]$. Then with $C_k = 5 \cdot 2^{k-1} - 2$,
$$
\left| \int_a^b e^{i \lambda \varphi(x)} \psi(x) \, dx \right| \leq C_k \lambda^{-1/k} \left( |\psi(b)| + \int_a^b |\psi'(x)| \, dx \right) \quad \text{for } \lambda > 0,
$$
for any $C^\infty$-function $\psi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, (i) if $k = 1$ and $\varphi'$ is monotone, or
(ii) if $k \geq 2$.

